# Nutiteq maps : Address search functionality in android

Tags: android, maps, nutiteq

I am using nutiteq maps,I want to add `Address search functionality`, Can I use google places api in `nutiteq map` so that on its search completed, a `marker` or a pin is dropped on nutiteq map or please suggest me any other related api to search address or rivers to fulfill my requirements.
Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically you can, but as far as I know Google does not allow to use their geocoding API with other maps. There are some free or cheap alternatives, depending on region of operation:

- Free and with global data: http://open.mapquestapi.com/nominatim/ - Nutiteq AdvancedMap3D has sample with this
- ESRI service (commercial): [ESRI ArcGIS REST API](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/#/Overview_of_the_World_Geocoding_Service/02r300000009000000/)
- With US data https://geocoda.com/ and many others